# how to access to choices in SimpleArrayFiled with a multiple choice filed using django forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

```
from model.blah import Ghosts
```

I have a model has a with a filed looks like this

```
scary_boos = ArrayField(
    choice_char_field(Ghosts.TYPE_SELECTION), blank=True, null=True
)
```

and in the admin panel, I am trying to add a form to show that field with pre-determined choices.

```
class GhostBoosForm(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    print(self.fields["mortgage_type"])
    self.fields["scary_boos"].widget = CheckboxSelectMultiple(
        choices=self.fields["scary_boos"].choices
    )

class Meta:
    model = GhostBoos
    fields = "__all__"
```

however `choices=self.fields["scary_boos"].choices` doesn't work is there any other way to access those choices of the filed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it that way, you'll need to access the `base_field` attribute of `self.fields["scary_boos"]`. `ArrayField` (which looks to be something that only works with PostgreSQL) basically stores it's first argument there, which I think in your case is a normal `CharField`(?)

More info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield

(I had to play around with `self.fields` a bit to find `base_field`, but it seems to give you access to what you need).

So: something like `self.fields["scary_boos"].base_field.choices[1:]` should do what you need. We "slice" off the first result because Django appears to insert the blank option `("", "-----")` (at least for me, Django 2.2.7).

Hope that helps.